# List header: show only some filters

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, sharepoint-list-filter

I have a JSON customized list view with about 15 columns. For the end user only about 5 of them are useful or should be available for sorting/filtering.

If I hide a column from the view, the information is also missing in the JSON customized list view.

How can I show only these 5 filters but keep all the info in my list?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how you are using filtering/sorting using JSON formatting? Is this a SharePoint default sorting/filtering?

Answer (score 1):

When the column you want to hide is also used in the JSON formatting, then JSON formatting will be invalid. It's by default.

As a workaround, I suggest you create two views. One is for JSON formatting, one is for end users filter.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, if you want to refer the column in JSON formatting, you have to show that column in list view.

If you remove the column from list view, JSON formatting will not work in this case.

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)